Compact Hausdorff Group Extension of Lie groups is Lie group
Let $K$ be a compact, Hausdorf topological group and $N\le K$ be a closed, normal subgroup. Suppose that $N$ and $L:=K/N$ are both Lie-groups. Can I conclude that $K$ admits a Lie group structure.
Does anyone know a counterexample or can give me a reference. Is this a consequence of Hilberts 5th problem or do I need some local connectivity assumption on $K$.

Consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow N\rightarrow K\rightarrow L\rightarrow 0$.  If this sequence splits, then $K$ admits a Lie group structure.

@MKhaledBin-Lateef But such a sequence need not split, so what do you have in mind?

@MKhaledBin-Lateef I believe, it would even suffice that there is $e\in U\subseteq L$ with $U$ open, such that  for $f: K \to L$  the induced map $f^{-1}(U)\to U$ has a continuous section.

It is easier than Hilbert-5.

I just thought it might be helpful to share the following.
It is actually the more general statement that is true.

Let $G$ be a topological group and $N$ a closed normal subgroup of
$G$. If $N$ and $G/N$ are both Lie groups, then $G$ it self is a Lie
group.

This statement was proved by Iwasawa, Theorem 7 in 1949.
A little later in 1951, the same result was obtained by Gleason, Theorem 3.1.
The proofs of Iwasawa and Gleason are quite complicated, but of course they do not use the solution of Hilbert's fifth problem.
It should be noted that the merit in the final solution of Hilbert's fifth problem for any locally compact groups belongs also to Gleason.
Also.
Von Neumann solved Hilbert's fifth problem in 1933 for compact groups.

I came up with the following proof.
By the Peter-Weyl-theorem for the compact group $K$ we might find
$$K \ge N_1 \ge N_2 \ge \dots $$a countable, directed subposet of the closed subgroups of $K$, denoted $\{N_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$, such that the canonical continuous homomorphism to the inverse limit $K\to{\lim}_{i\in \mathbb{N}} K/N_i$ is an isomorphism, and such that $K/N_i$ are compact Lie groups. As $K/N\cap N_i  \le (K/N_i) \times (K/N)$ and $\lim_{i\in \mathbb{N}} K/N_i\cap N \to  \lim_{i\in \mathbb{N}} K/N_i$ is clearly surjective with kernel $\bigcap N_i/N\cap N_i =\{1\}$. So, we might assume that $N_i\le N$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$ and that $N_1=N$. In particular, all $N_i$ are compact Lie groups.
The quotient dimensions stabilize:
The short exact sequence of Lie groups $0 \to N/N_i \to K/N_i \to K/N\to 0$ shows that $\dim K/N_i = \dim L + \dim N/N_i \le \dim L + \dim N$. We conclude that there is $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dim K/N_i = \dim K/N_k$ for all $i\ge k$ and consequently $N_k/N_i$ is finite, discrete.
Now $N_k\to \lim_{i\ge k} N_k/N_i $ is a continuous isomorphism. As $N_k$ is compact Lie and $\lim_{i\ge k} N_k/N_i$ is profinite, we conclude that $N_k$ is finite and discrete. The short exact sequence $0\to N_k \to K \to K/N_k \to 0$, then shows that, as topological space, $K\cong \sqcup_{n \in N_k} n(K/N_k)$, from which $K$ inherits the structure of a Lie group.
Alternatively, one can also deduce the result from the following theorem of Palais, see Proposition 4.5 here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/slice+theorem. The action of $N$ on $K$ is free and proper, $K$ is compact, Hausdorff and $N$ is Lie group. So, $K \to K/N =L$ is a $N$-principal bundle. Thus, $K$ admits the structure of a smooth manifold. Thus by Hilbert's 5th problem, (a weaker version of it), $K$ is a Lie group.
